# How to set screen orientation to portrait mode on Android TV App?

Tags: android, screen, orientation, android-tv

I have an **Android TV App**, that needs to change its activity to **portrait** mode. Already set the `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` but no success.

Note: On the emulator it did work at Android 6 but not at Android 9.

I also tried it programatically but it was the same result: `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`

I also found out that there is an App ([Set Orientation App](https://freeapk.mobi/set-orientation/)) which can rotate the Systems Screen completely.

How can I achieve the same result on my Android TV App?

My intention is to switch the Screen orientation during runtime on specific conditions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have root access on the tv, you can edit probs to change it to the screen orientation.

Comment: Hi @Hunter and welcome to StackOverflow. Device rooting should not be encouraged. You also might want to look at how to write a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer It might be tedious but it will be worth your while.